# Different response :SRVE0260E The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts2 framework in my application

When we try to access the page which is not available
for some page it goes to my defined error  page  and in some cases it didn't goes o proper error page

```
www.mytestsite.com/a/  - goes to proper 404 error page as defined in web.xml

www.mytestsite.com/p/  - goes to
```

SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

Original Exception:

```
Error Message: SRVE0190E: File not found: /p/
Error Code: 404
Target Servlet: DefaultExtensionProcessor
Error Stack: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /p/ 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:572) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3944) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebC
```

My web.xml file is configured with

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/test/404Error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
<error-page>
```

Please help to suggest any solution for the above issue

Comment: Show your filter mapping in web.xml, correctly modified with /a or /p as for the rest of the code

Comment: Could you post a folder structure of the web root?